# Как можно через add_filter перевести текст плейсхолдера в конкретном инпуте, а не во всех, где используется данная языковая переменная?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть плагин фильтрации FacetWP. В нем имеется текстовое поле для фильтрации между min и max параметрами. Это поле на сайте используется несколько раз. По умолчанию в нем везде указаны плейсхолдеры из языкового пакета плагина: min, max.
Хотелось бы заменить этот текст на свой, в зависимости от ситуации. В доках есть такой пример перевода:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
  if ( 'fwp-front' == $domain ) {
    if ( 'Number' == $translated_text ) {
      $translated_text = 'Enter a number';
    } elseif ( 'Min' == $translated_text ) {
      $translated_text = 'Minimum';
    } elseif ( 'Max' == $translated_text ) {
      $translated_text = 'Maximum';
    }
  }
  return $translated_text;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Вот интересно, а можно ли как-то доработать этот фильтр, чтобы в идентичных инпутах, внутри родителей-дивов с разным классом, был разный перевод плейсхолдеров?

Comment: Такие вопросы нужно задавать производителю. Плагин мало того что платный, так и не особо популярный. Вероятность что он у кого-то есть и он станет разбираться с твоей задачей стремиться к нулю.

Comment: Тут вопрос не по плагину, а по вордпрессу add_filter.  Есть или нет в нем такая точечная возможность перевода. Так понятней?

Comment: У тебя есть условие - "в зависимости от ситуации". А эту ситуацию реализует плагин. Вот когда в "зависимости от ситуации" плагин будет выводить разный текст, тогда можно будет говорить о переводах. Так понятно? А документация по функции тут https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_filter